# functional components nesting vs. props

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, inner-classes

i'm pretty new to React and I have a question regarding Architecture & Design Patterns. I've finished my first project (an [interactive turing machine sequencer](http://reactiveturing.herokuapp.com/) if anyone is interested. I caught myself declaring nested functions quite frequently e.g

```
function MyReactList(props){
   const items = []
   for (let i=0; i<20;i++){
      function MyReactElem(props){
         return <div>
            <h1>{getHeadingFromSomewhereUsingIndex(i)}</h1>
            {getTextFromSomewhereUsingIndex(i)}
         </div>
      }
      
      items.push(<MyReactElement></MyReactElement>)

   }
   return items

}
```

On closer inspection I realized that this is probably completely pointless, because it's 100% equivalent to:

```
function MyReactList(props){
   
   function MyReactElem(props){
      return <div>
         <h1>{getHeadingFromSomewhereUsingIndex(props.index)}</h1>
         {getTextFromSomewhereUsingIndex(props.index)}
      </div>
   }

   const items = []
   for (let i=0; i<20;i++){
      items.push(<MyReactElement index={i}></MyReactElement>)
   }
   return items

}
```

And if i'm not mistaken the 2nd Version should use signifcantly less memory?
Should I even nest functional components like that at all? My idea was working under the paradigm that every qualifier should be declared from the smallest context possible but maybe thats wrong because I'm not sure what other implications it has, would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints, if nested functional components are ever a good idea and when that is the case.

Comment: There's no advantage to declaring a component within another component, but there are disadvantages. Everytime `MyReactList` re-renders, `MyReactElem` has to be redeclared. If your subcomponents have state, you may also notice bugs with them losing their values/reseting to original state, since they must be re-mounted when the parent re-renders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested function components are not a good idea. Why not? Because everytime `MyReactList` renders, it will redeclare `MyReactElement`. This means that a new place in memory will be allocated for `MyReactElement` every time `MyReactList` renders. Because functions get compared by their memory address, and since `MyReactElem` gets put into a new memory address each render, react will think that the current `MyReactElem` is an entirely differen component from the `MyReactElem` of last render. This causes a unmount of the previous `MyReactElem` (lose all state) and a mount of the current `MyReactElem` (initialize) instead of rerender.

If you keep state, you lose it which obviously can lead to nasty bugs. But even if you do not, it is way more expensive for react to remount than to rerender.

Comment: Yeah I can see  more clearly now, that it is a really bad idea, I  was starting to think so before but now I'm starting to see just how bad it **really** is. I'm a little bit supprised that react doesn't spew out any warnings on that though, but maybe there is actually some cases where it's unavoidable. Thanks for the help!