# Advantages of rendering a component vs a function returning JSX [React]

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I understand that, within your React component, it's always good to render a component rather than use a function that renders some JSX.
What I mean is,

Doing this :

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const someRenderFunction = () => <p>Hey</p>;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {someRenderFunction()}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((c) => c + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment{" "}
      </button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

is NOT encouraged. The render function should be exported into it's own Component, like this :

```
const HeyComponent = () => <p>Hey</p>

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeyComponent />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((c) => c + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment{" "}
      </button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I never really understood the benefits of this refactor. I tried placing checking the re-render behaviours, unmount behaviours. Still didn't see any difference.
Can anyone explain in detail why this refactor is necessary/beneficial ?

Answer (score 4):

This is all about `components`, so components should be reusable and should follow the `DRY` principle, in your case that seems to be so simple and just as you said will prevent the `someRenderFunction()` to be re-rendered if there aren't any changes to that component in the `virtual dom` so the best practices are to use `<X />` syntax always or for some cases `const Y = <X />` also is more readable. testing is another reason to create more components and make them more decoupled. imagine here you need to pass `props` to your `someRenderFunction()` so you will lose the jsx feature for passing props as `<X prop={PROP}/>`.

Comment: DRY stands for Don't Repeat Yourself

Answer (score 3):

The actual difference between the two is that the function returning JSX is not a component, so it does not have its own state. When you use `useState` in the function, the state change will cause the `App` to be re-rendered.

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons why the second way is better than the first way are:

1. The function which defines the `<p>Hey</p>` JSX (named `someRenderFunction` in the first way, and `HeyComponent` in the second) is moved outside of the component `App` in the second way. As of now, there's no benefit, but if you later wanted to extend `someRenderFunction`/`HeyComponent` to have normal component lifecycle that can be hooked into, moving it outside of `App` would be essential. For example, if you wanted the function/component to keep track of its own state, the first way would cause `someRenderFunction`'s state to get reset every time `App` renders. More info on this problem can be found here: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unstable-nested-components.md, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64211013/693855.
2. `HeyComponent` would be seen as a valid component whereas `someRenderFunction` would not, because component names need to start with a capital letter (this is mentioned here https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component in the Note at the bottom of the section). If you used hooks in your function, and it was not seen as a valid component by React, it would be breaking the "Rules of Hooks" set by React (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). I'm not sure if this would cause any bugs, but it is frowned upon by React -- if you have the "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks" ESLint rule enabled (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), you would see an error like this: `ESLint: React Hook "useState" is called in function "someRenderFunction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)`

Answer (score 1):

The code which renders a component is followed as best practice.
Using Components we can pass state values to child component and can be used to display data. The same component can be re-used in other places.

If you have to just display a small function it can be used too if it shows constant information.